# 16.04 Project display to smart TV wirelessly

Tags: 16.04, display, screencast, wifi-direct, smart-tv

Does anyone know how to project or screencast the display to a smart TV wirelessly?
I don't want to use HDMI or any corded connection.

I just want to use my smart TV for work purposes and I want to project the display wirelessly.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: nope I gave up hahaha
sadly I'm not that good at tinkering linux. I'm new to linux